# Activity layout android ImageView, ImageButton scaling

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve something of the format as shown in the image. The blue part is background, the image of the guy and girl is a ImageButton. The original images for these are 88x128 (trainer000, trainer001). I want to rescale the ImageButton such that the image covers the entire height and the width is adjusted accordingly. Now I found 2-3 ways to do so but they make use of a separate class to calculate width. I want to know if there is a way to do it purely in the xml file itself.

What I used:

`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/maleimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/trainer000" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/femaleimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/trainer001" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Are you a boy or a girl?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

`

What I want is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wGnX.jpg

EDIT: Found the solution. I just used Studio's Layout editor.

Comment: use scaletype: center/crop

Comment: @WARpoluido center crop won't always use vertical as its limiter. You have to use a custom class, or manually calculate and resize the image so it always fits perfectly height-wise, but flexible width-wise.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I was looking for a way without making a class. It seems there is no other way. I'll go on with making a class for it.